# Columns are squeezed when export from SSRS to excel

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2012

I've created report, but when I export to excel then some columns are squeezed. I can expand them but how to force SSRS not to squeeze the columns?
[image]

Expanded:
[image]

**UPDATED**: It seems that report xml was corrupted. I've created report from the scratch and now it works.

Comment: This is an SSRS issue with merged headers. See this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how_to_eliminate_merged_and_hidden_cells_issue_from_excel_export_of_ssrs_report/2013/05/17/how-to-eliminate-merged-and-hidden-cells-issue-from-excel-export-of-a-ssrs-report/

Comment: Try removing the header and place the header content in Tablix first row. Also try making CanGrow and CanShrink as false for each detail row cell

Comment: @MiguelH didn't help.

Comment: @DrHouseofSQL  CanGrow/Shrink didn't help. I removed all headers and all merged cells. Nothing helped

Comment: The Excel renderer tries to produce output that looks identical to the report. If you have columns that are no exactly aligned, it will add blank columns to pad the gaps.

Make sure that in the whole of your report, columns line up exactly if possible, this includes stuff outside your main tablix and if your tablix is not pushed up to the left edge of the report then you will get a blank column A in your excel output (as you have in your example)

Comment: I create a separate report for exporting purposes. Then you can just write an expression to hide the matrix if it's not an export and vice versa.

Comment: I created report from the scratch again and now it works